# Don't understand " + objID +"

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript, so I can not understand the meaning of `" + objID +"` then comes this.

```
timer[objID]=setTimeout(m,150);
```

Here is all the code. If needed you could copy/paste it in your editor to see the result. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>TEXT</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">      **/*the css */**
            html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
            h1 { margin-top: 30px }
            #menu a, .subMenu a {
                display: block;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 10pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;                     
            }
            #menu a:hover, #menu a:active, .subMenu a:hover, .subMenu a:active {
                background-color: #eee;
                border-color: #999;
            }       
            #menu {
                background-color: #ddd;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #menu a {
                width: 100px;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            .subMenu {
                width: 150px;
                top: 26px;
                background-color: #ddd;
                border: 1px solid black;
                position: absolute;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .subMenu a {
                display: block;
                width: 90%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 4px;
            }
            #subMenu1 { left: 5px }
            #subMenu2 { left: 125px }
            #subMenu3 { left: 230px }

        </style> **/*the css ends*/**

                   <script type="text/javascript">
            var timer= new Object(); 

            **/* this func. sets the visibility
            of hidden menus which appear by
            "onmouseover"*/**

            function setVisibility(objID, visible){ 
            var obj=document.getElementById(objID);
            if(obj.style.visibility=visible){
                obj.style.visibility="visible";
            }
            else{obj.style.visibility="";}

            }

            **/* this one calls the func. above
            if needed to show the hidden
            menu*/**

            function showMenu(objID)
            { setVisibility(objID,true);
                clearTimeout(timer[objID]);
            }
            **/*this one hides by onmouseout putting false boolean in func.                          
                     setVisibility "visible" parameter*/** 
            function hideMenu(objID)
            { 
                var m="setVisibility('"+objID+"',false)";
                timer[objID]=setTimeout(m,150);
            }


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Text</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#" 
                onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu1')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu1')">Module 1</a>
            <a href="#" 
                onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu2')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu2')">Module 2</a>
            <a href="#" 
                onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu3')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu3')">Module 3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="subMenu1" class="subMenu"
        onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu1')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu1')">
            <a href="../module1/statements/for-1.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module1/statements/if-1.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module1/statements/switch.html">Text</a>    
        </div>

        <div id="subMenu2" class="subMenu"
        onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu2')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu2')">
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/array.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/boolean.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/date.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/global-object.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/math.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module2/objects/build-in/number.html">Text</a>
        </div>
        <div id="subMenu3" class="subMenu"
        onmouseover="showMenu('subMenu3')"
                onmouseout="hideMenu('subMenu3')">
            <a href="../module3/document.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module3/history.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module3/location.html">Text</a>
            <a href="../module3/navigator.html">Text</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very poor way to hide the menu after a short interval of time.

You better change that to:

```
function hideMenu(objID)
{ 
    timer[objID] = window.setTimeout(function() {
        setVisibility(objID, false);
    }, 150);
}
```

The `setTimeout` method can also accept raw string, which it then *evaluates* and executing on the fly. Evaluation in JavaScript (used also by `eval()` method) is not a good practice and better be avoided when possible. In this case it can be easily avoided by passing a function to `setTimeout`.

Focusing yet deeper on syntax, let's take this line:

```
var m="setVisibility('"+objID+"',false)";
```

This is creating a string and adding the value of a variable called `objID` inside it, wrapping it with single quotes so that it will be passed as a string. If for example the value of that variable is `T250` the resulting string would be:

```
setVisibility('T250',false)
```

Comment: thanks very much, but can you explain the syntax of this ' "+objID+" '. I mean the two layer quotes.

Comment: @KarenKhasikyan sorry, don't understand what is still not clear to you. Can you explain?

Comment: Thank you, I understood your edit, and yes, it seems more logical to me, but the only question I have is that why do I need to receive my result in objID with single quotes. Is it for receiving data as a simple text and not as another variable.

Comment: @KarenKhasikyan because without the quotes the string would look like `setVisibility(T250,false)` then when evaluated, it will search for variable called `T250` and crash with error since such variable does not exist. So yes, it's for "receiving data as simple text" like you said. :)

Comment: Ok, don't be angry, my friend, I'm just starting :)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you this function:

```
function hideMenu(objID)
{ 
     var m="setVisibility('"+objID+"',false)";
     timer[objID]=setTimeout(m,150);
 }
```

First the variable `m` is set to a string. This string is wrapped in `"`. But the you need to add the variable `objID` to the string. So the string is closed with a `"` a plus (+) is used to connect the variable `objID`. (The parameter of `hideMenu`). Then this string gots again connected to another string.

That means if you call

```
hideMenu( 10 )
```

The variable `m` is the to: `setVisibility('` and the content of `objID`, in this case 10 and `',false)`

`setVisibility('10',false)`

Answer (score 0):

```
“ setVisibility ( ' ” + objID +“ ' , false ) ”
```

Is a concatenation of three elements.

```
“ setVisibility ( ' ” 
objID 
“ ' , false ) ”
```

The first and last are strings and the objID is converted to a string in this context.

So if objID is '14' you get the value (string)

```
“ setVisibility ( ' 14 ' , false ) ”
```

assigned to your variable *m*

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `objID` is a variable, which is equal to a `key` of a `object` and one of the syntax's to refer to a `object` attribute in javascript is

```
objectName[keyName]
```

when you use this method, you can enter a `string` with quotes (e.g. `"myKey"`) or a variable name, with the other method

```
objectName.keyName
```

you can only enter a string, without quotes.

so `timer[objID]=` would mean that there is a `object` called `timer`, to which the a attribute is being added, and its being called whatever the current value of `objID` is.

in this specific case (`timer[objID]=setTimeout(m,150);`) its a timed function to be run, which can be canceled later with `window.clearTimeout(timer[objID]);` - providing `objID` still has the same value.